# Why does printf give me the following output?

Tags: c

I'm working through *The C Programming Language book* and understand that if I had a line of code like:

```
int c;
printf("%d", c = 5);
```

I will get an output of 5, because (c = 5) has the value of the RHS value of the assignment.

In a similar way:

```
int c;
printf("%d", c = getchar(c));
```

will give me the integer value of the first char in the stdin buffer, because (c = getchar()) has the value of the RHS which is just the getchar() function.

I was playing around with it and used the following using VS Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, b;
    printf("%d\t%d", c = (b = 7));
}
```

The output I get is:

7
6422376.

and not

7
7

Why is this? The second output is the same value (6422376) no matter whatever value I use for b, eg (b = 3).

Comment: You are only printing one number and not two numbers. When printf tries to read the second number it reads something random in memory.

Comment: Re “the value of the RHS value of the assignment”: In general, the value of an assignment expression is the value of the **left** operand after assignment. For example, given `unsigned char x;` (with eight-bit bytes) or `int y;`, the value of `x = 356` is 100, and the value of `y = 3.5` is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `c = (b = 7)` is a *single* expression, and as such a single argument passed to the `printf` function.

The second `%d` format specifier leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as there is no second argument matching it.

Answer (score 1):

because for second %d there is no matching argument as c=(b=7) is a single expression

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well-formed : you have only one parameter for printf when you should have two.

Comment: Thank you! I see now there is only one comma and so only one value. b is presumably some random value already assigned in memory (or undefined behavior).

Comment: @BenHall - the problem isn’t with `b`, it’s that there’s no argument corresponding to the second `%d` conversion specifier *at all*.  `printf` is expecting two values but you’re only passing one (the result of `c = (b = 7)`), so it grabs some garbage value from where it expects the second value to be.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, b;
    printf("%d\t%d", c = (b = 7),b);
}
```

you can try these code to print the value of b. There is only one parameter in your printf function, and 2 format specifier, so compiler assumes any garbage value for another %d.

Comment: This is undefined behavior as the arguments are evaluated in unspecified order, and `b` may be evaluated before it is initialized.